# Perl: Accept User Input in if-else statement

Tags: perl, input, if-statement

I am accepting User Input in an If-Else block. Check Code:

```
if ( $svr == 1 ) {
    print "Enter Datbase Name\n";
    my $db = <>;
    chomp($db);
} elsif ( $svr == 2 ) {
    print "Enter Data Source Name (DSN)\n";
    my $db = <>;
    chomp($db);
}
```

When I am referring to $db in a later statement, I am getting the following error:

"Use of uninitialized value $db"

This is the statement in which I am using $db that is  causing the error:

```
my $data_source = 'DBI:mysql:' . $db . ':' . $host;
```

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first `$db` is scoped to the "then" block, and teh second `$db` is scoped to the "else" block. You need declare the `$db` var before the `if`.

```
my $db;
if($svr==1) {
 print "Enter Datbase Name\n";
 $db=<>;
 chomp($db);
} elsif($svr==2) {
 print "Enter Data Source Name (DSN)\n";
 $db=<>;
 chomp($db);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define `$db` outside of the if/else block. By defining it inside of the block you are limiting the scope of the variable to those blocks:

```
my $db;
if($svr==1) {
  print "Enter Datbase Name\n";
  $db=<>; 
  chomp($db);
} elsif($svr==2) {
  print "Enter Data Source Name (DSN)\n";
  $db=<>;
  chomp($db);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the `my` statement declares a variable inside a scope, i.e. the curly braces. It is not defined outside. If you put the `my $db` outside the if/else block, it should work. If there is no common scope, you have to make it a global variable using `our`. See `perldoc -f my` for details.

Answer (score 1):

You have the answer, but unless there is more logic that I'm not seeing, you might make it even easier on yourself ...

```
if($svr==1) {
  print "Enter Datbase Name\n";
} elsif($svr==2) {
  print "Enter Data Source Name (DSN)\n";
}

my $db=<>;
chomp($db);
```

or even

```
print $svr==1 ? "Enter Datbase Name\n" : "Enter Data Source Name (DSN)\n";
my $db=<>;
chomp($db);
```

This is more than just cosmetic. Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) is important because, in the future, if you need to change something, you might not remember to change it in each location. This is a proactive step to writing good code.

If there is more logic in those if statements, try something like

```
sub prompt {
  my $question = shift;
  print $question . "\n";
  my $response = <>;
  chomp $response;
  return $response;
}

my $db;
if($svr==1) {
  $db = prompt("Enter Datbase Name");
} elsif($svr==2) {
  $db = prompt("Enter Data Source Name (DSN)");
}
```